# Difficulty dynamically adding a border around a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a "Terms and Conditions" checkbox, and when "Place Order" is clicked, among other things, I want to validate that Terms&Conditions is checked, and if not, add a thin red border around the surrounding div.  I am unable to get the following to work though.

```
if (!terms.checked) {
    console.log(terms.parentNode.parentNode);
    terms.parentNode.parentNode.style.border = '1px red';
    //terms.parentNode.parentNode.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    //terms.parentNode.parentNode.style.borderColor = 'red';
}
```

I know my Javascript is getting the correct node, as when I log it to console and then hover over it, it highlights the element.  As you can see from the commented out lines I've tried adding `borderWidth` and `borderColor` individually, but also to no avail.

I've referred to both https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style and cannot figure out what I should be doing differently.  I've also created the following fiddle to no avail: https://jsfiddle.net/LLdozham/

[image]

Comment: Add a style to your border? `1px solid red`

Comment: the default value of the border-style is **none**  his means that if you change the border-width and the border-color, you will not see the border unless you also change this property to something other than none 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style

Comment: Thanks everybody

Comment: Why revenge-downvote when you can vote to close as a duplicate?  There, I did it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention what your `border-style` property should be. The `border-style` property specifies what kind of border to display.

You need to mention either one of the followings as `border-style` value depending on your needs:

```
dotted - Defines a dotted border
dashed - Defines a dashed border
solid - Defines a solid border
double - Defines a double border
groove - Defines a 3D grooved border. The effect depends on the border-color value
ridge - Defines a 3D ridged border. The effect depends on the border-color value
inset - Defines a 3D inset border. The effect depends on the border-color value
outset - Defines a 3D outset border. The effect depends on the border-color value
none - Defines no border
hidden - Defines a hidden border
```

**Usage:** `terms.parentNode.parentNode.style.border = '1px solid red';`

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to add `solid` so: `1px solid red`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add the border style solid, as in '1px solid red'